# pass a html text in an input field using HTML DOM by innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in geting the html content from a div am pass it into an input field 
I'm using the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="void"> 
<div id="main"><strong>Hello</strong> my friend</div>
</div>
<br>
<input type="text" id="resul" >
<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
x=document.getElementById("void").getElementsByTagName("div");
document.write("Text of first paragraph: " + x[0].innerHTML);
document.getElementById("resul").value=x[0].innerHTML;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you will try it, you will see what I mean. By using the command document.write() I get the value that I need from de div tag : "Hello my friend" but when I want to pass this value "Hello my friend" into an input field I get something like this "**Hello** my friend". 
How can I pass into the input field only the text "Hello friend" without  tag.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById("main");
document.write("Text of first paragraph: " + x.innerHTML);
document.getElementById("resul").value= x.innerHTML;
</script>
```

to pass the content without the tag you can use

```
x.textContent || x.innerText;
```

so:

```
var x = document.getElementById("main");
var text = x.textContent || x.innerText;
    document.write("Text of first paragraph: " + text);
    document.getElementById("resul").value = text;
```